# Design Pattern for DAO tests with jUnit

Tags: design-patterns, junit, dao

I am looking for a best practice to test a DAO class with jUnit. My DAO class has a couple of typical DAO methods like createUser(User user), deleteUser(Long id), updateUser(User user), findUserById(Long id)...

So createUser could be easy, I could create a user and check if it has an id afterwards. If yes the test would pass. 
Or would you rather create a User, read the User from the DB afterwards and check if it 
1) finds the user
2) the instance variables from the returned user are the same like from the user saved before

Now what about the deleteUser function? It takes an ID, but in order to obtain the ID I would first have to create a User. So how to do this? Use the testCreateUser method from the test method or the createUser method from the DAO class?

Same thing with updateUser(User user) where I need a User to be updated first and findUserById(Long id) where I need an Id first.

I think my requirement is pretty common so I am wondering if there is something like a design pattern for testing DAOs with jUnit.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO a unit test should be able to run by itself.

So for example a delete test will first create a user then delete it and check that it does not exist anymore (by trying to load it).

Relying on previous tests is not a good way because if the previous test fails for any reason, the next test will also fail.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO there is no such design pattern for doing the JUnit testing. There are best practices that you have to refer to.

For example, in below case you don't use testCreateUser method to create the user before you delete. You have to use the DAO class for that. Each test case method is independent of each other.

> Now what about the deleteUser function? It takes an ID, but in order
>   to obtain the ID I would first have to create a User. So how to do
>   this? Use the testCreateUser method from the test method or the
>   createUser method from the DAO class?

Now, to solve your problem you can use setUp and tearDown method. In setUp method you can create the mock objects that you want to test and in tearDown you can delete them. If you do so each testmethod will get the same set of mock data on which you can test.

Answer (score 1):

My usual approach is to use the other methods of the DAO within the same test.  For example

```
user = UserStore.create(...);
id = user.id();
loadedUser = UserStore.load(id);
assertThat(loadedUser, eq(user));
```

If you take this approach, the "unit" in unit testing is the class as a whole, whereas you typically unit test a function at a time. This is acceptable and will result in a well-tested class. The issue with this approach is that a failed test could be due to an error in UserStore.create or UserStore.load, but I've found that with small classes, it's not hard to debug and tends to work really well. I've tried other approaches where I manually check the database after the test, but I've found the extra work isn't usually worth it.

Some frameworks, like Rails, take a different approach. They provide a way for you to seed the database with data before your tests run. This works well, because the framework makes it easy. Maybe this will become the norm as more tools provide support for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an in memory database That is filled with your test data before every test and gets discarded after test execution finishes. Take a look at [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevdvlpinmemdb.html)

Another thing to consider is, should you really unit test your DAO layer? Dao's should not contain business logic by definition and you end up testing the persistence framework.